# non-default location of NER models in Stanford Corenlp

Tags: stanford-nlp

Stanford Corenlp by default uses the three NER models in the following order:

> Loading classifier from
>   edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz ...
>   done [20.6 sec].  Loading classifier from
>   edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.conll.4class.distsim.crf.ser.gz
>   ... done [16.4 sec    Loading classifier from
>   edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.muc.7class.distsim.crf.ser.gz ...
>   done [18.2 sec].

But, if we want to load our own models from a location in my computer, which property do we have to set ?

Because, if I extracted the contents of stanford-corenlp-3.2.0-models.jar and added my models to it and recreated the jar file and recompiled corenlp. But while loading the newly added classifier, I get the following error:

```
     [java] Adding annotator tokenize
     [java] Adding annotator ssplit
     [java] Adding annotator pos
     [java] Reading POS tagger model from edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/english-left3words/english-left3words-distsim.tagger ... done [13.2 sec].
     [java] Adding annotator lemma
     [java] Adding annotator ner
     [java] Loading classifier from edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/ner-model-twitter.ser.gz ... java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to edu.stan
ford.nlp.sequences.FeatureFactory
     [java]     at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier.loadClassifier(CRFClassifier.java:3380)
     [java]     at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier.loadClassifier(AbstractSequenceClassifier.java:1587)
     [java]     at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier.loadClassifier(AbstractSequenceClassifier.java:1642)
     [java]     at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier.loadClassifier(AbstractSequenceClassifier.java:1629)
     [java]     at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier.getClassifier(CRFClassifier.java:3526)
     [java]     at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.ClassifierCombiner.loadClassifierFromPath(ClassifierCombiner.java:133)
     [java]     at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.ClassifierCombiner.loadClassifiers(ClassifierCombiner.java:117)
     [java]     at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.ClassifierCombiner.<init>(ClassifierCombiner.java:99)
     [java]     at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.NERClassifierCombiner.<init>(NERClassifierCombiner.java:62)
     [java]     at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP$6.create(StanfordCoreNLP.java:555)
     [java]     at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorPool.get(AnnotatorPool.java:81)
     [java]     at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.construct(StanfordCoreNLP.java:260)
     [java]     at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:127)
     [java]     at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:123)
     [java]     at StanfordCoreNLPXMLServer.main(StanfordCoreNLPXMLServer.java:121)
     [java] Loading classifier from edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/ner-model-twitter.ser.gz ... Exception in thread "main" edu.stanford.nlp.io.RuntimeIOException: java.io.F
ileNotFoundException
     [java]     at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP$6.create(StanfordCoreNLP.java:559)
     [java]     at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorPool.get(AnnotatorPool.java:81)
     [java]     at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.construct(StanfordCoreNLP.java:260)
     [java]     at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:127)
     [java]     at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:123)
     [java]     at StanfordCoreNLPXMLServer.main(StanfordCoreNLPXMLServer.java:121)
     [java] Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException
     [java]     at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.ClassifierCombiner.loadClassifierFromPath(ClassifierCombiner.java:143)
     [java]     at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.ClassifierCombiner.loadClassifiers(ClassifierCombiner.java:117)
     [java]     at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.ClassifierCombiner.<init>(ClassifierCombiner.java:99)
     [java]     at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.NERClassifierCombiner.<init>(NERClassifierCombiner.java:62)
     [java]     at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP$6.create(StanfordCoreNLP.java:555)
     [java]     ... 5 more
     [java] Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to edu.stanford.nlp.classify.LinearClassifier
     [java]     at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.ner.CMMClassifier.loadClassifier(CMMClassifier.java:1074)
     [java]     at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier.loadClassifier(AbstractSequenceClassifier.java:1587)
     [java]     at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier.loadClassifier(AbstractSequenceClassifier.java:1642)
     [java]     at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier.loadClassifier(AbstractSequenceClassifier.java:1629)
     [java]     at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.ner.CMMClassifier.getClassifier(CMMClassifier.java:1114)
     [java]     at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.ClassifierCombiner.loadClassifierFromPath(ClassifierCombiner.java:139)
     [java]     ... 9 more
     [java] Java Result: 1

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 3 minutes 22 seconds
```

Answer (score 1):

The `-ner.model` option will attempt to find the file on the Java classpath *or* as a filesystem path. If you give an absolute path to the `ser.gz` file on your filesystem, it should load fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think the FileNotFoundException is bogus/misleading, and the problem here is the first error with the ClassCastException from ArrayList to FeatureFactory.  I think this shows that you have on your classpath and are running an **old** version of CRFClassifier, from before when we retrofitted CRFClassifier to support having a List of FeaturyFactory's.  I'd check carefully what's on your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the recompiled models.jar have your custom model with props file in the expected path(edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/) by extracting it.